# what "default definition would be ill-formed" means?

Tags: c++

Im a begginer on c++, im try to creat an object but im getting an error, and i dont understand what wrong. this is my hpp file + cpp file when im getting the error:

```
Manager::Manager(const Manager &manager ) :
Worker(manager.name,manager.id,manager.salary){
   this->workers=manager.workers;
}

class Manager:public Worker {
    private:
    std::vector<Worker> workers;         
    public:
        Manager(const char* name, int id, int salary);
        Manager(const Manager &manager );      
};
```

error:

```
In file included from Manager.hpp:5:0,
                 from Manager.cpp:1:
Worker.hpp:7:7: note: ‘Worker& Worker::operator=(const Worker&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class Worker{
```

but when im doing this it workes:

```
Manager::Manager(const Manager &manager ) :
    Worker(manager.name,manager.id,manager.salary), workers(manager.workers){
               }
```

someone can tell me why?

---

edit:

this is the worker class code:

this is worker.hpp

```
  class Worker{
        protected:
            const std::string name;
            const int id;
            int salary;

        public:
            Worker(const std::string& name, int id, int salary);
            Worker(const Worker& worker );
    };
```

this is worker.cpp:

```
#include "Worker.hpp"

Worker::Worker(const std::string &names, int ids, int salarys) :
name(names), id(ids), salary(salarys)
{
}

Worker::Worker(const Worker &worker): 
name(worker.name), id(worker.id), salary(worker.salary)
{

}

Worker::~Worker() {

}

std::string Worker::toString(){
    std::string s="Worker id:" + id ;
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Default assignment operator generated by compiler by performing assignment for each field. So if one of them is const-qualified or is not copyable compiler fails to emit assignment operator. Most likely `Worker` class (that you should've posted in your question) contains one or more of such fields.

Note that calling `this->workers=manager.workers;` will invoke copy assignment operators for each `Worker` stored in `worker`, while calling `workers(manager.workers)` will invoke copy constructors, which is well-defined.

Comment: hey, thanks for your fast answer, I add the worker class code. I still don't understand why I get this error.

Comment: @EliorSastiel `Worker::name` and `Worker::id` are const-qualified so when compiler emits code for assignment operator `this->name = other.name;` it will be ill-formed.

Comment: @EliorSastiel You declare `name` as `const std::string name;` so it is not possible to assign anything to it after it has been initialized at constructor. This is the same as `const int x(25); x = 85;`.

Comment: When I run : `workers=manager.workers` inside the constructor, I activate the `operator=`. Currect me If I'm wrong, the `vector::operator=` will create new element for each element in `manager.workers` by using copy consturctor. So the `name` will be copied by value.

Comment: Let us see ur code about operator=.  u may not implementation of that operator, but u use that. right?

Comment: @EliorSastiel  Calling `workers=manager.workers` involves instantiation of `Worker::operator =` even if `workers` on the left side are empty and copy can be performed by copy construction. Therefore you get an error.

Comment: @Jake i dont have `operator=`

Comment: Yeah.. u need to implementation of that operator. It will solve that problem.

Comment: @Jake It can not be implemented because class is not copy assignable. And it is not required anyway because `workers(manager.workers)` works fine and should be preferred anyway.